# Puppeteer: How to open an actual new window instead of tab?

Tags: puppeteer

Every time you do `await browser.newPage();` - Puppeteer opens a new tab in the same browser window. But I need an actual new window with bookmarks bar and stuff, so popups open via JS won't work.

Comment: More details and context seem needed to avoid an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876). What page are you testing/scraping where it's necessary to do this? Please provide a link or a [mcve] of the page markup/JS behavior, and the data you hope to extract from it.

Answer (score 3):

To open new windows (browser instances) you will need to call [`await puppeteer.launch()`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&show=api-puppeteerlaunchoptions) more times. Note that it will use more resources than if you'd open new tabs.

You might find useful the concept of [`BrowserContext`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&show=api-class-browsercontext) in Puppeteer, where you can make use of [`browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext()`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&show=api-browsercreateincognitobrowsercontext).

Example from the docs:

```js
// Create a new incognito browser context
const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
// Create a new page inside context.
const page = await context.newPage();
// ... do stuff with page ...
await page.goto('https://example.com');
// Dispose context once it's no longer needed.
await context.close();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, David! Unfortunately it does not help in my case - I'm using `puppeteer.connect({ browserWSEndpoint})` in order to connect to an existing browser session (context?), and by the same reason - incognito windows won't help me. Yes, I'm aware of higher resources usage when it's different windows, not tabs.